# while adding some html code using jquery to a div the html tag didnot show its iffect on added text

Tags: jquery-selectors

i am trying to add this code to my html page using jquery $('div').html() method.
it will add text only not the image or not the effect of p, br, h1 tags on that text

```
<section>
   <article>
    <h1>Click HQ >></h1>
    <p>monday 20th August 2012 
    <img alt="click HQ"" src="14.png" />
    </p>
    <h1>rent sign >></h1><br/>
    <p>monday 11th August 2012
    <img alt="rent sign"" src="rent.png" />
    </p>
      </article>
   </section>
```

Comment: the double angle brackets surely must be causing an issue...

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? I was able to get the html and append versions to work in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nNXk6/). Are you seeing the raw html added to the page? Put another way, are you seeing this "<h1>Click HQ >></h1>" or this "Click HQ >>"